# Integral equation numerical solution

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Do you know how I can solve the following integral equation numerically?

$x\sqrt{x}f\left(x\right)+\int_x^a\frac{tf\left(t\right)dt}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)t-\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right]}=f_0\left(x\right)$

$f_0\left(x\right)$ is a known function (its values are tabulated for a set of points), $a$ is a known parameter.

I have to find $f\left(x\right)$ for the given points.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use trapezoidal rule to approximate the integral term and solve the resulting system of linear equations. Let $x_0 = 0, x_N = a, h = \frac{a}{N}, x_i = i h$. For simplicity let's introduce $p(x) = x\sqrt{x}, g(t, x) = \frac{t^2}{(\sqrt{t} + 1)(t\sqrt{t} + t - x)}$.
Then the equation in form
$$
p(x) f(x) + \int_x^a g(t, x) f(t) dt = f_0(x)
$$
can be approximated with
$$
p(x_i) u_i + h \sum_{j=i}^{N-1} \frac{g(t_j, x_i) u_j + g(t_{j+1}, x_i) u_{j+1}}{2} = f_0(x_i), \qquad i = 0, 1, \dots, N-1\\
p(x_N) u_N = f_0(x_N)
$$
which is an upper-triangular system of linear equations in $u_0, \dots, u_N$, each $u_i = f(x_i)$. The system can be easily solved by back substitution.

This is a general method and it can fail if $g(t,x)$ is singular somehow (those square roots might become a problem). Anyway, that requires more info about the problem.

Comment: Thank you, the function has no singularities in the interval I work with, so it should be doable. One question though, how did you get $g\left(t,x\right) = \frac{t^2}{\left(\sqrt{t}+t\right)\left(\sqrt{t}+t-x\right)}$?
I get a slightly different answer:
$g\left(t,x\right) = \frac{t^2}{\left(\sqrt{t}+t\right)\left(\sqrt{t}+t-\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)}$

Comment: @MartinNikovski Fixed, thanks. Hope it's right now

Comment: One more question. What is the difference between $u_j$ and $f_j$?

Comment: Another typo, should be $u_j$

Comment: Aha, thanks for the clarification, makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you solve it numerically, probably you can solve $f(x)$ out for each $x$, then you can plot $(x,f(x))$ and observe what is kind of function of $f(x)$ is and then do a function fitting.

In order to do so, you should do a little linear algebra first for your original integral function. You could differentiate the function in both sides, and you would be get something like:

$3/2\sqrt(x)f(x)+ x\sqrt(x)f^{'}(x)-\frac{xf(x)}{(1+1/\sqrt(x)[(1+1/\sqrt(x))x-1]}=f_0^{'}(x)$

Then you can use numerical methods to solve this differential equation with respect to $x$, such as using forward difference method or central differential method.

Comment: In $\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^a g(x,t) dt$ you get additionally to the derivative for the boundaries $-g(x,x)$ also the derivative of the integrand, $\int_x^a \frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,t)dt$.

Comment: Alright, I thought of turning it into a differential equation, but can you write a little more detailed explanation of how you differentiate the integral. Since it is an integral from $x$ to $a$, I use Leibniz integral rule, but the equation gets way too complex, plus it still contains an integral. How do you get rid of that integral?
Edit: Yes, exactly as LutzL says.

Comment: Martin, oh I just realized that the integral could not be dropped out by differentiation as I posted. I made a mistake when I used the Leibniz rule. 

I think this problem must be from a real engineering problem, so probably you could know something about the possible form of $f(x)$, then you can transfer your problem into parameter estimation problem.

If you do not know the format of $f(x)$ at all, it seems that using differential method could not be simply solve the problem based on what you provided.